# Bootstrap 3 carousel white background underneath slide when sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the latest version of Bootstrap on my website. Every time the carousel slides, a white background appears below the slide image.

Where is this coming from and how do I get rid of it? Images are of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

> May its the default background color of the carousel or something underneath .
>   
> To find the origin of that , try overriding the background color of carousel or body or html or may be the container underneath it with a different background color .
>
> To avoid that change height of images to

```
height:100% ; or height:"100vh";
```

> if the above doesn't work also set height for the html/body element

Comment: height 100% does not work and there is a problem with setting height to 100vh that it stretches the picture and it looks very ugly.

Comment: then you should use  nice big images.

Comment: or you can set all images to same height , it will look nicer than this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height of the image to 100% so that it covers the entire height of the carousel container.  To do this you will have to set all of the images parent containers to 100% also you will have to give your `.carousel` a specific height.  So you will have to set the`.carousel` to something like height: 500px and then set the `.carousel-inner`, the `.item` and the `.item img` all to `height: 100%;`.  If you want to preserve the resolution of the image then you can get rid of the image tag and give each slide another class eg. `.slide-one`, `.slide-two`, `.slide-three` ect.  Then you can give each of these classes a background image and set it to cover but you will still have to set the carousel height to a certain height and then set `.carousel-inner` and `.item` to `height: 100%`.  Here is an example fiddle that I show people to make their carousels truely responsive.  It uses padding bottom to the `.carousel-item` and then you set this to a percentage.  Then mess with this padding-bottom percentage to get your desired height.  And then set each item to have a background image.  Here is the fiddle that you may want to look at

[Carousel Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/6s5u8de1/)

But to get your carousel to work you need to do like I stated earlier and set the image and it's parents containers height to 100%.  If you don't want to mess with any of that you can resize your images to all be the same size with many of the webs image resizers you can just google resize image to find one.

Hopefully this all helps